# Update all rows that are grouped by date where two conditions are matched - SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server

I have a temp table that contains the following data:

[image: Example Data]

The `WV1` column needs to be updated to the department value for all rows that share the same date for example;

```
WV1 = 19176 for all 2017-11-08 00:00:00.000 rows
WV1 = 18067 for all 2017-11-06 00:00:00.000 rows
```

The `WV1` column may remain as NULL if there is no 215 code but it doesn't matter for my purposes, I can't create other temp tables meaning I'm restricted to CTE or subqueries, thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following using CTE:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT IDNO, [DATE], DEPARTMENT
FROM #TAB
WHERE CODE = 215
)
UPDATE T
SET WV1 = C.DEPARTMENT
FROM #TAB T
JOIN CTE C ON C.IDNO = T.IDNO AND C.[DATE] = T.[DATE]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, for my particular case scenario this worked a treat!!